# MySQL error 1064 - where is the mistake?

Tags: mysql

```
$query =  "UPDATE rastliny2 

SET nazov1='$nazov1', nazov2='$nazov2', poznamka='$poznamka',
kontajner='$kontajner', velkost='$velkost', cena=$cena, cena2=$cena2,
obrazok='$obrazok', not_show=$not_show 

WHERE id = $id";
```

I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `obrazok='', not_show='1' WHERE id = 1` at line 1

cena, cena2 and not_show are numbers

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' obrazok='', not_show='1' WHERE id = 1' at line 1

Comment: I think there is an issue with your quotes

Comment: The bigger issue is that you're cobbling SQL together by hand.  :P  Look into prepared statements.

Comment: Write full generated sql, with parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If i had to guess, it seems `$cena2` is either null, an empty string, or the boolean value `false`.  Any of those will stringify as nothing, resulting in SQL like `..., cena2=, obrazok=...`, which is invalid SQL.

You'll want to filter your values before stuffing them into the query.  And/or wrap everything in quotes -- MySQL is fine with that.  It might lead to odd values getting inserted, like `0` if you tried to insert `'true'`.  That's where filtering and/or validation will come in.

But you don't have to do this.  Every modern database API offers the ability to prepare a statement.  That lets you separate the SQL and the data, and makes it so you almost don't have to care about your SQL breaking due to invalid data.  (If your data is not what MySQL considers valid, it may well store the wrong thing...so you should still validate.  But you won't get MySQL errors.)

The code to prepare and execute an UPDATE statement in PDO looks a bit like:

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare('
    UPDATE rastliny2 
     SET nazov1=:nazov1, nazov2=:nazov2, poznamka=:poznamka,
         ...other params...
     WHERE id = :id
');

// and to run the query...
$ok = $stmt->execute(array(
     ':nazov1'   => $nazov1,
     ':nazov2'   => $nazov2,
     ':poznamka' => $poznamka,

     ... other params, in no particular order ...

     ':id'       => $id,
));

// You can tell PDO to throw exceptions instead of returning false.
// If you do, then you don't need this.
if (!$ok) {
    // oh noes
}
```

The code for mysqli is a little bit uglier, and a bit less self-descriptive, but it can be done there as well.

If you're using `mysql_query`, you can't prepare a statement.  You'll have to continue doing the machine's work for it.  But if you're still using it, then you deserve the punishment anyway.  The mysql extension is deprecated, and should not be used in modern code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = 'UPDATE rastliny2 SET nazov1="'.$nazov1.'", nazov2="'.$nazov2.'",
poznamka="'.$poznamka.'", kontajner="'.$kontajner.'", velkost="'.$velkost.'",
cena="'.$cena.'", cena2="'.$cena2.'", obrazok="'.$obrazok.'", not_show="'.$not_show.'"
WHERE id="'.$id.'" ');
```

Edit: you can do other ways, but this is my preferred way (escape the string to handle variables)

Another edit: debug your queries by echoing your php variables before the query to make sure all values are as expected. (a tip to narrowing the search)